# Возможность и производительность JSON в MySQL и его сравнение с EAV

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, eloquent, eav

Всем привет. Встал вопрос в гибкой реализации свойств товаров в интернет-магазине, т.е. паттерн "1 свойство = 1 сущность" не подходит, ибо необходима возможность создания свойств без создания дополнительных таблиц в БД. Сейчас думаю о 2 вариантах: использовать EAV или хранить все данные в доп.столбце товара в JSON'e. Появилось несколько вопросов касаемо данной темы:

1. Общие данные - насколько хорош в производительности тот или иной вариант?
2. Как я понял из документации Laravel, Eloquent дает вариант "из коробки" редактировать JSON в модели без дополнительных велосипедов. Но где лучше хранить начальные атрибуты всех товаров? Т.е. при создании товара, админ должен получать все возможные атрибуты для товара, как это правильно реализовать? Отдельная таблица `product_attributes`?
3. Что делать с полями, которые должны быть заполнены только определенными вариантами, т.е. в админу должен показываться список/чекбоксы/радиокнопки и т.д.? Создавать отдельную таблицу `product_attribute_value`? Если да, то я практически реализовал EAV

Сразу хочется добавить, что ИМ на Laravel 5.5, MySQL 5.7 + Redis для кэша

Comment: Тоже заморачивался на этот счет, в итоге пришел к нескольким таблицам - `products` - товары, `product_variants` - модификации, `product_characteristics` - все характеристики и `product_variant_characteristic` - связка модификации и характеристики со значением.

Comment: Это по аналогии с сервисом МойСклад. У товара может несколько модификаций, например - кеды разных цветов и размеров. Модификация товара будет иметь две характеристики - цвет и размер. Например кеды красные 42, кеды красные 44, кеды черные 42, кеды черные 44